# If A is countable $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is dense. Clarify one line in proof? Ways to improve?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the proof I was given:

Proposition.- If $A$ is countable then $\mathbb{R} \setminus A $ is dense.

Proof:
Suppose otherwise, then there exists real numbers $a$ and $b$, with $a < b$, such that there is no $a < x < b$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A $. To put it in another way, if $a < x < b$ then $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A$, as $ \mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is the complement of $A$, we see that if $a < x < b$ then $x \in A$. Thus,$(x,y) \subseteq A$. But $A$ is countable and $(x,y)$ is not, this leads to a contradiction. QED.

Is it correct to assume that $(x,y)$ is uncountable because it is not dense? That all countable sets are dense? (That non-dense sets are uncountable?)

What would be the rule that governs why $(x,y)$ is not countable?
Is there anything wrong with this proof?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $(x,y)\subset A$ ? What's $y$ ? And no, countable sets are not necessarily dense, I'm sure you know several counter-examples.

Comment: Did you mean $(a,b)\subseteq A$ instead $(x,y)\subseteq A$?

Comment: The "rule" that $(x,y)$ is not countable is that every nonempty interval has cardinality $\left|\mathbb{R}\right|$.

Comment: As the proof was given to me it said (x,y). In either case, assuming y $\in \mathbb{R}$ OR, if it should have been (a,b) what are the implications?

Comment: @Augustin This is the only proof I have (out of textbooks and class notes) proving this specific proposition. Rereading it I can assume y $\in$ A and share the same properties as x. I understand through the point in the proof "x $\in $ A" and I understand afterwards that any uncountable set cannot be a subset of a countable set. I don't know why an open interval was brought into the proof? Perhaps because A $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so since intervals are a characteristic of $ \mathbb{R} $ they can be applied to A as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No open interval is countable. A well-known proof of that is the so called Cantor's diagonal argument. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#Real_numbers).

Not every countable set is dense. Take $\Bbb N$, for example. But others, are: $\Bbb Q$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{\frac1n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a countable set which is not dense.
The [Cantor set](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is an uncountable set which is not dense.
Hence denseness is not related to countability, but we are sure that every dense set on the real line must be infinite.
There is a general result in mathematics known as Baire category theorem which asserts that

> If $A$ is a set of first category in the real line, then $\mathbb R/A$ is dense.

And your statement is an special case of the above theorem, because every countable set is of first category.

Comment: I have not learned about Baire categories yet, and I need to stick to what I've been told, but I look forward to learning about it I the future.